# Profile Image upload in angular 2 not getting uploaded

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular2-template

I am new to angular and I am creating a profile page. When I try to upload a profile image I get the error POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/avatar/jja 500 (Internal Server Error).
When I view the error in the network tab it says  {"error":"No file found"}.

Below is my code

profile.ts

```
public onFormSubmit({ value, valid }: { value: any, valid: boolean }) {
    let profile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("profile"));
    this.accountDetails = profile.user;
    this.user = value;
    this.api.post("/users/avatar/" + this.accountDetails.username, value, true)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.api.get("/users/" + this.accountDetails.username, true)
          .subscribe((response) => {
            profile.user = response.data
            console.log(this.accountDetails.username)
            localStorage.setItem("profile", JSON.stringify(profile))

            this.accountDetails = profile.user;
            this.user = this.accountDetails;
            console.log("2", this.user)
            location.href = "/profile"
          }, (err) => {
            alert("Update failed " + err);
          })
      }, (err) => {
        alert("Update failed " + err);
      })
  }
```

profile.html

```
<div class="col-md-3">
                    <form novalidate (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit(imageUpload)" #imageUpload="ngForm">
                      <div class="profile-pic" style="background-image: url('http://www.sheffield.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/placeholder.png')"
                      >
                      {{accountDetails.avatarUrl}}
                      </div>
                    <input type="file"
                        placholder="Change Image"
                          name="avatarUrl"
                          [(ngModel)] = "user.avatarUrl" 
                          #avatarUrl = "ngModel">
                          <p  class="form-submit ">
                              <input  type="submit" value="Update" class="button color small submit">
                            </p>

                    </form>
                  </div>
```

Comment: Try putting the original file in assets folder. Angular doesn't allow any other folder to be accessible unless you do some configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You cannot simply upload the file like this using angular models.

You have to use either formdata or  convert the file to base64 then upload the profilepic.

Here is how you can convert file to base64

readFileData(file:File):void{
        var _this=this;

        if (file) {
let fileModel:FileModel=new FileModel();
          fileModel.fileType = file.type;        
          fileModel.fileName = file.name;
          fileModel.fileExtension = '';

          if(file.name.lastIndexOf(".") >= 0){
            fileModel.fileExtension = file.name.substr(file.name.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
          }
          fileModel.fileSize = file.size;

          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsBinaryString(file);

          reader.onload=function(e){
            _this._handleReaderLoaded(fileModel,e);
          }
}
_handleReaderLoaded(fileModel:FileModel,readerEvt):void {
        let binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
        fileModel.base64String=btoa(binaryString);
      }

on backend convert again from base64 to file.
```